# pyttsx3 stopped working after updating to macOS Ventura

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyttsx3, macos-ventura

Here is the code that I wrote earlier on Python3.11.
`

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('nsss') # object creation

TTS_RATE = 150          # speed of tts
TTS_VOLUME = 1.0        # volume of tts
TTS_GENDER = "Male"     # gender of tts (Male or Female)
"""RATE"""
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')   # getting details of current speaking rate
engine.setProperty('rate', TTS_RATE)     # setting up new voice rate
"""VOLUME"""
volume = engine.getProperty('volume')   # getting to know current volume level (min=0 and max=1)
engine.setProperty('volume', TTS_VOLUME)    # setting up volume level  between 0 and 1
"""VOICES"""
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
if TTS_GENDER == "Male":
    voiceGenders = filter(lambda voices: voices.gender == 'VoiceGenderMale', voices)
elif TTS_GENDER == "Female":
    voiceGenders = filter(lambda voices: voices.gender == 'VoiceGenderFemale', voices)
for voice in voiceGenders:
    if voice.languages == ['en_US']:
        engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

def va_speak(phrase):
    engine.say(phrase)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.stop()

va_speak("Hello there")
```

`Originally I ran this code on Monterey and it worked perfectly fine. As the update installed, it threw me this error:`

```
File "./voice assistant/tts.py", line 18, in <module>
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 146, in getProperty
    return self.proxy.getProperty(name)
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 173, in getProperty
    return self._driver.getProperty(name)
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 69, in getProperty
    return [self._toVoice(NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributesForVoice_(v))
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
    return [self._toVoice(NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributesForVoice_(v))
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 64, in _toVoice
    attr['VoiceAge'])
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_convenience_mapping.py", line 18, in __getitem__objectForKey_
    return container_unwrap(res, KeyError, key)
  File "./voice assistant/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/objc/_convenience.py", line 122, in container_unwrap
    raise exc_type(*exc_args)
KeyError: 'VoiceAge'
```

`

The initializing of the pyttsx3's engine goes without any errors, but if I try to get voices, it shows me the same error as described earlier
`

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('nsss')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
```

`
Already tried reinstalling pyttsx3, launching the code with sudo, which didn't help a lot
Changing the argument in init (pyttsx3.init('dummy')), passed through without any errors but there was no sound what so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to the OS upgrade to Ventura. I encountered the same issue after upgrading from montery to ventura. While waiting for `pyttsx3` to fix the issue, you can update the following [line](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/blob/master/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py#L64). You can find the file to be updated with the following snippet:

```bash
$ python -c 'import inspect; from pyttsx3.drivers.nsss import NSSpeechDriver; print(inspect.getsourcefile(NSSpeechDriver))'
```

It gaves me something like :

```
/Users/myuser/virtualenvs/myvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py
```

Once you have located the file, update it using your preferred code editor to remove `attr['VoiceAge']`. Once you have done this, it should work as before.

Comment: yes, the issue disappears but the audio gets terrible.

Comment: @Rachid - did you find a solution? Do you have an M1 processor or no? (The Macbook M1 is my issue (I believe))?